# Only a CSS class not working, all other CSS are working fine

Tags: css

I am currently working on a web development project.

The problem is that all other CSS are working fine but there is a CSS class for a form just doesn't work. I've no idea what to do.

```css
.actLeadClaims form {
  margin:40px 25px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width:465px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.actLeadClaims h1 {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.actLeadClaims input[type="text"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="password"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="date"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="datetime"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="email"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="number"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="search"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="tel"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="time"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="url"],
.actLeadClaims textarea,
.actLeadClaims select {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.actLeadClaims input[type="radio"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
}

.actLeadClaims select {
  padding: 6px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.actLeadClaims button {
  padding: 19px 39px 18px 39px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #4bc970;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #3ac162;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.actLeadClaims fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.actLeadClaims legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.actLeadClaims label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.actLeadClaims label.light {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline;
}

.actLeadClaims .number {
  background-color: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="actLeadClaims"> 
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
      <label>Product Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="productName">
      <label>Product Brand:</label>
      <input type="text" name="productBrand">
      <label>Product Series:</label>
      <input type="text" name="productSeries">
      <label>Comment:</label>
      <textarea rows="6" name="productDesciption"></textarea>
      <label>Picture:</label>
      <input type="file" name="coverToUpload" id="coverToUpload"></br></br>
  </fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="uploadProduct">
</form>
</div>
```

However, all these code end up look like this:

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Paste some of your code that doesn't work. so we can help you.

Comment: We shouldn't ask for code, you need to paste it in here. We can't help you if you don't paste your code.

Comment: Add your code snippet so others can understand what exactly you are facing

Comment: Sorry guys, the codes are added. Please have a  look :)

Comment: CSS is being applied correctly as far as i can tell: https://jsfiddle.net/xstq04qp/ what's not working here? PS. that's not how you `<br />`

Comment: @haxxxton it just somehow end up like this [Screen Shot](http://imgur.com/a/AI0HF)

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very descriptive, what, exactly is the issue you are encountering?

Comment: @steveax sorry about that but really no idea what is wrong with it. The css and html look good to me, but it end up all in mess. Please have a look at this [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/AI0HF)

Comment: If you could provide what you expect it to look like, it would help immensely.

Comment: The code you provide work fine, there is no issue.

Are you using any other css or css file with the code?

Comment: The provided code is working fine. Please provide a snippet that reproduce your problem otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: Probably, you add this class the last one. Delete browser´s cache and reload the page.

Comment: It works now when I split all the css for the form into another css file. Any idea what was wrong?

Comment: You probably had an error in the css file; a missing semicolon or curly brace or something like that, just before the CSS you're showing here. You can check a CSS file for errors with the [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've used BR tag in a wrong way. BR is written `<br>` or `<br />` not `</br>`.

After that, you didn't specify what's your problem but I guess it's about locating labels regularly and make the form look good. If it's so, try the solution below. First, you correct BR tags:

```
<div class="actLeadClaims"> 
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
      <label>Product Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="productName">
      <label>Product Brand:</label>
      <input type="text" name="productBrand">
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <label>Product Series:</label>
      <input type="text" name="productSeries">
      <label>Comment:</label>
      <textarea rows="6" name="productDesciption"></textarea>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <label>Picture:</label>
      <input type="file" name="coverToUpload" id="coverToUpload"><br><br>
  </fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="uploadProduct">
</form>
</div>
```

Then add/modify CSS codes this way:

```
.actLeadClaims input[type="radio"],
.actLeadClaims input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
}

.actLeadClaims select {
  padding: 6px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.actLeadClaims button {
  padding: 19px 39px 18px 39px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #4bc970;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #3ac162;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.actLeadClaims fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.actLeadClaims legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.actLeadClaims label {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.actLeadClaims label.light {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline;
}

.actLeadClaims .number {
  background-color: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-radius: 100%;
}
input,
textarea {
  vertical-align: top;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Take a look at the form in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arashtad/szzekvdd/4/). Please expand the output part to see it widely.